# What does this Export and Import syntax mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at the code of some libraries and in one of them I saw this syntax:

```
export const v4: v4;  // What's the meaning of this export style, is it an object?
```

And then during import I noticed someone imported it as thus:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');  // Also, what is the meaning of this import style?
```

This leaves me confused from the normal way I usually export and import.

Comment: The second one's standard destructuring from the object require returns. The first looks like it's a _type_ - it's not just JS.

Comment: Is it possible you are looking at TypeScript?

Comment: The first snippet isn’t valid JS and it doesn’t appear to be valid TypeScript either. `const` declarations must be initialized.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh I see!! The first one was typescript

Comment: @SebastianSimon My tots as much but actually I lifted that code exactly as it is from a typescript type declarations file and it appears valid kind of even though I had my doubts as well.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Concerning Standard Object destructuring. I know of the following formats:

1. ```const{v4}=require('modulename');```

and for defaults one can still say ```const{v4=10}=numbers;``` 

Is ```const{v4=10}=numbers``` the same as ```const{v4:10}=numbers``` during destructuring?

Comment: `const{v4:10}=numbers` isn't valid syntax, because `10` isn't an identifier. That destructuring is to _alias_ the imported name, it's like doing `const uuidv4 = require(...).v4`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Perfect explanation!!!. Now I understand. Thank you so much